# form does not set config form controls after reset and initialize in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

In my angular app I have a form with some fields: inputs, datepicker, selects,...

First, in ngOnInit() I initialize the form group calling an initilizeForm() function where I created the form group and I set some config like form control disabled or its "default" value.

Then, the user writes some info and then I save the form group data. After that, I reset the form to have a clear state form and then I call again the initializeForm function to set default values. But, at this moment, the function does not do anything and I do not know why.

Initialize call in OnInit:

```
public formGroup: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
  this.initializeForm();
}
```

Initialize function:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      input1: [
        { value: '', disabled: true },
        [Validators.XX, Validators.YY]
      ],
      input2: [
        { value: '', disabled: false },
        [
         Validators.XX, Validators.ZZ
        ]
      ],
      select1: [
        { value: 'Value1', disabled: true },
        [Validators.XX]
      ]
//.... more fields
});
```

Reset form after "save"

```
  public savedOk() {
    this.formGroup.reset();
    this.formGroup.enable();
    this.initializeForm();
  }
```

I do not know why when I call initialize form in ngOnInit form group is created as expected and then, if I call initialize form the form group does not show form controls with the value set in that function.
select1 should be disabled and should have the option with Value1 selected.

It can be solved with this.formGroup.get('fieldName').setValue('Value1')
and with .disabled() but I would like to use initialize function for that.

I am using Angular 7 and angular material.

Example Template example:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput name="inputName" formControlName="inputName" required />
    </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>label</mat-label>
    <mat-select placeholder="label" formControlName="select1">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let op of options, trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="op.value">{{
                op.label |
                translate }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Looking more info I think I should use the next in on save:

```
   this.formGroup.reset({
      select1: { value: 'Value1', disabled: true }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show me the HTML code? also you dont need to initialize the form after the reset.

Comment: Look at this example I created for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqun6r Check your formGroup definition and HTML for that. If you have some asynchronous calls, then look at this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity().

Comment: I have added an HTML example code. I think I should use reset with config object when it is necessary

Comment: Thanks Gregor, but my select input is not disabled and does not have the option selected using your solution :/